# rotate and its properties

Tags: html, css, webkit, rotation

When using

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);;
```

does its properties rotate with it or do they stay the same, for example does the margin top become the left, or does margin top stay at the top?

Think it's me being stupid but having some weird things happing when trying style the elements

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on the browser. See this example: http://jsbin.com/ihico

IE and firefox do not rotate the margin, while webkit does.

For consistency, try using padding on the container instead.